# Unable to start domain with https

Tags: ssl, https, amazon-ec2, haproxy

I am working on `haproxy`. I want to make my site open with `http`. I have purchased ssl certificate and install on the server.

In `ha.cfg` I have configured as follow :

```
 global
    tune.bufsize    32786
        tune.maxrewrite 16384
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1  notice
    maxconn 8192
    user    haproxy
    group   haproxy
    daemon

 defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option  redispatch
    balance roundrobin
    stats   enable
    stats   refresh
    stats   uri /ssproxy_stats
        stats   realm   Haproxy\    Statistics
        stats   auth    haproxy:haproxy
    maxconn 4000
    contimeout  5000
    clitimeout  50000
    srvtimeout  50000

 frontend http
    bind    *:80
    acl hari path_beg /customers
    acl css path_beg /assets
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    use_backend appointpress_app if hari
    use_backend appointpress_app if css
    default_backend appointpress_site

 frontend https
    bind    *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/ssl.key/mydomain.crt
    default_backend appointpress_site

 backend    appointpress_app :80
    stats   enable
    stats   auth    haproxy:haproxy
    cookie  SERVERID    insert
    option  httpclose
    option  forwardfor
    server  app_server  ec2-elastic-domain:80   cookie  haproxy_app check

 backend    appointpress_site :80
    stats   enable
        stats   auth    haproxy:haproxy
    cookie  SERVERID    insert
    option  httpclose
    option  forwardfor
    server  wordpress   someip:443  cookie  haproxy_site    check
```

After running the command `haproxy -f ha.cfg` I am getting no error,

and when I am running url `http://ec2-instance`, its working fine

but while running `https://ec2-instance`,

I am getting error :

in chrome : Error code: `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

in firefox : Error code: `ssl_error_rx_record_too_long`

How to resolve the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that your EC2 security rules allow port 443 to your running instance. A simple way to test this is to use telnet from your client:

```
telnet ec2-instance 443
```